# How to make correct iptable rule like browser port configuration

Tags: linux, python-2.7, iptables, serve

After searching the forums with no matching results, I asking hear.

I want to redirect every browser request in destination port 80 to another port (for example 8080). all in the localhost.

My workplace is `linux`, and I want to use the `iptables` rules and `python` code server.
The rule I used is:
`iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080`.
 I also tried some other flags like specific ip source and server etc.

The server listening on port 8080 is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

def redirect_factory():
 class RedirectServer(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
   def do_GET(self):
       self.send_response(301)
       self.send_header('Location', 'www.IdontCare.IdontKnow')
       self.end_headers()
 return RedirectServer

redirectServer = redirect_factory()
handler = SocketServer.TCPServer(('', 8080), redirectServer)
print("serving at port %s" % 8080)
handler.serve_forever()
```

The problem is that it works well when I configure my browser in the `connection settings` (without adding the iptables rules) like this:

[image]

But when I use the iptables rules it says that it have a broken pipe, and the browser request didn't received at all in the server. So if I write in the URL in the browser *www.google.com* I can't see it with the `self.path` value.

**EDIT:**
Here is the `iptables -t nat -nvL --line-numbers` output:

[image]

the rule is working, but it not done what I suppose.

I play a little with the rules, and if I put one of the next rules I can see in the CNAME in the `self.headers` value.
the rules is (I can just choose one of them):

> 1. `iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 80`
> 2. `iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1`

If I not mistake, both of them done the same thing.

what am I do wrong ?
and how to make it work with iptables rules like the configuration of the browser?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the results of sudo iptables -t nat -nvL --line-numbers here

Comment: Thank you for help _Mystic monk_ . as you can see, the rule work fine, but i'm not receive what i expect.

Comment: Some of the things you can try are
1. Check if the rules are indeed being hit - see the packet counter values increasing after each request
2. Check if there are multiple interfaces to your device, in which case you have to add these rules on all the interface.

Comment: Thanks. 
1. indeed, the rule hit well. but I'm not sure if I use the correct rule, or maybe I need to put another rules.
2. no, I have only `loopback (lo)` and `eth0`.

Comment: Can you try adding the same in the prerouting chain?

Comment: The prerouting doesn't  work here, because it redirect only traffic from outside, but here the request from the browser came from the local machine (loopback).